# Error al inicializar Angular 7

Tags: angular

Chico estoy empezando un curso de Angular , todo bien al instalar pero cuando quiero inicializarlo con el comomando : ng serve -o
me sale este error, alguien sabe porque?

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open
>   your browser on http://localhost:4200/
>
> Date: 2018-10-22T20:01:43.741Z Hash: 0c26e8dbe590cccf6136 Time: 3114ms
>   chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.95 kB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 94.6 kB
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map
>   (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.js,
>   styles.js.map (styles) 16.6 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {vendor}
>   vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 326 kB [initial] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in Could not resolve module /C/clase de Angular/3.-Aplicación- i
>   ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Prueba en tu tsconfig.json `"compilerOptions": { "baseUrl": "./",... }`

Comment: suena a que angular no encuentra un modulo, revisa la referencia que te indica el CLI, o trata de compartir el codigo que estas tratando de ejecutar. Saludos!!